# XSLT correct approach in writing XPath expression used in multiple condition checking and displaying value

Tags: xslt

Considering this XML,

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <book>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <count>available</count>
    </book>
    <phone>
        <brand>nokia</brand>
        <model></model>
    </phone>
</items>
```

**Mapping Criteria while writing XSLT:**

- show the newbook/newtitle only if a value is present in input.
- show the newbook/newcount only if a value is present in input.
- show the newphone/newbrand only if a value is present in input.
- show the newphone/newmodel only if a value is present in input.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="book" select="items/book" />
    <xsl:variable name="phone" select="items/phone" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <items>
            <newbook>
                <xsl:if test="$book/title!=''">
                    <newtitle>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$book/title" />
                    </newtitle>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$book/count!=''">
                    <newcount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$book/count" />
                    </newcount>
                </xsl:if>
            </newbook>
            <xsl:if test="$phone/brand!='' or $phone/model!=''"> <!-- not sure if this condition is required for the above mapping criteria -->
                <newphone>
                    <xsl:if test="$phone/brand!=''">
                        <newbrand>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$phone/brand" />
                        </newbrand>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$phone/model!=''">
                        <newmodel>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$phone/model" />
                        </newmodel>
                    </xsl:if>
                </newphone>
            </xsl:if>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my concern:- In my actual XSLT, I have almost 70 conditions like
this, and everytime the XPath search is made twice [or thrice.. ] for
each condition [ for eg: `<xsl:if test="$phone/brand!=''">` and `<xsl:value-of select="$phone/brand" />` and outer `if` condition].

Is this much performance overhead? I don't feel it when I ran my application.

I like to hear from experienced people if this is correct way of writing the XSLT. Do I need to save the path in a variable and reuse it as done for `$book`
and `$phone` ? In such a case there will be 70+variables just to hold this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this quite differently using templates.  If you define a template that matches any element whose content is empty and does nothing:

```
<xsl:template match="*[. = '']" />
```

or possibly use `normalize-space()` if you want to consider elements to be empty if they contain only whitespace

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

Now with this in place add templates for the elements you *are* interested in

```
<xsl:template match="book">
  <newbook><xsl:apply-templates /></newbook>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <newtitle><xsl:apply-templates /></newtitle>
</xsl:template>
```

and so on.  Now the `book` template will create a `newbook` element and go on to process its children.  When it gets to the `title` it will have two different templates to choose from and will pick the "most specific" match.  If the title is empty then the `*[. = '']` template will win and nothing will be output, only if the title is non-empty will it create a `newtitle` element.

This way you let the template matcher do most of the work for you, you don't need any explicit conditional checks using `xsl:if`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <items><xsl:apply-templates select="items/*" /></items>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore empty elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />


    <xsl:template match="book">
      <newbook><xsl:apply-templates /></newbook>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
      <newtitle><xsl:apply-templates /></newtitle>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- and so on with similar templates for the other elements -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Clearly understood. I was going through the answer multiple times to ensure i understood completely. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to ask one clarification - <xsl:apply-templates /> means <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> means to 'apply the templates to all the child nodes'. Hence, need not we mention <xsl:apply-templates select ="*" /> // 'apply the templates to all the child elements' ? please confirm.

Comment: @prash `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` - all the child _nodes_ of the current element, which includes text nodes and comments as well as child elements.

Comment: So, if I have a comment node inside my `<book>` element, then isn't it better to write the template as `<xsl:template match="book">
      <newbook><xsl:apply-templates select="*" /></newbook>
    </xsl:template>`  ?

Comment: @prash you could, but the default handling for comment nodes is to ignore them completely, it's only if you have an explicit template matching `comment()` or `node()` that it may matter. I just stuck to using the same form for all the templates - you definitely don't want the `select="*"` for title, for example, as there you need to include the text nodes.

Comment: Yes for title I should not use that.  Thanks for mentioning on comment processing. Everything is clear. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have a peculiar behavior as mentioned in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640457/xslt-getting-two-different-output-for-same-input-xml-for-same-xsl .

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Ian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21584916/1078110), you can also make a generic template that will create the "new" elements for you without having to specify each one individually. That would look like the below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <items><xsl:apply-templates select="items/*" /></items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space())]" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('new',name())}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That last template just rebuilds the element by concatenating the word "new" to the front of it.

Comment: In this specific scenario, combined with Ian's approach, this way of concatenating works well. In my real case, the new elements are having different names. But, Thanks for mentioning the concat() method. I started thinking, using templates are better than 'if' conditional checking and for loops.